# EXC_BAD_ACCESS SQL DATABASE

Tags: objective-c, sql, xcode

I got this exc_bad_access problem in AppDelegate.m
What I did and want is to have multiple sql query. To avoid complexity, I did two blocks (it will have more) and both are querying different table from sql.

```
-(void)readDataFromDatabase {

    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Initialize the budgetobjects Array
    Part1Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from part1TBL";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


                // Read the data from the result row
                // You can add more rows based on your object
                NSString *Part1_Name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *Part1_Description = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                // Create a new Restaurant with the data from the database
                Part1 *newPart1 = [[Part1 alloc] initWithName:Part1_Name description:Part1_Description];

                // Add the budgetobject to BudgetObjectsrantArray
                [Part1Array addObject:newPart1];

            }
        }

        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);


    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database2;

    // Initialize the budgetobjects Array
    Part2Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from part2TBL";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


                // Read the data from the result row
                // You can add more rows based on your object
                NSString *Part2_Name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *Part2_Description = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                // Create a new Restaurant with the data from the database
                Part2 *newPart2 = [[Part2 alloc] initWithName:Part2_Name description:Part2_Description];

                // Add the budgetobject to BudgetObjectsrantArray
                [Part2Array addObject:newPart2];

            }
        }

        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database2);





}



@end
```

The exc_bad_access highlighted at the end where

```
sqlite3_close(database2);
```

Comment: Raw SQL?! Really? What a waste of time.  At least use a decent wrapper like FMDB.  Better still, use Core Data as it has excellent integration with Mac OS X, iOS and iCloud.  This day and age, hand-rolling SQL is a sure sign you are doing it the hard way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with sqlite, but it looks like the issue with your code is that you're never opening 'database2'. Instead, you open 'database' twice, which looks like a typo.

// Open the database from the users filessytem
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &**database**) == SQLITE_OK) {

....

sqlite3_close(**database**);

...

// Open the database from the users filessytem
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &**database**) == SQLITE_OK) {
// <--- This should be **&database2**
...

sqlite3_close(**database2**);

EDIT: Please note Mat's answer as well - there's several places where you're using database when you meant to use database2, and you might want to consider just reusing database, or extracting this functionality into a shared function if applicable.

Comment: The rest of that second block needs to be updated to use `database2` too. (Or just re-use the `database` pointer and forget about `database2` altoghether.)

Comment: Im still learning. am seriously studying on core data too.. and to Josh, yup, the codes you rewrite is good to go! thank you very much! now its running on device